# how to handle null value in the table in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table having one field "SUSCRIBER_ID" and structure of the table is that SUSCRIBER_ID field should not be null. Now, i want to update the value of that field with below conditions.

```
UPDATE table_name SET SUSCRIBER_ID = DECODE (REGEXP_REPLACE (SUSCRIBER_ID,'^\D*',NULL),NULL,SUSCRIBER_ID);
```

error is coming name SUSCRIBER_ID can not be null however when REGEXP_REPLACE is return the null value then i am skipping the records

data is in the table

```
name
---------
sumit123sumit
```

Please assist

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table_name SET SUSCRIBER_ID = DECODE (REGEXP_REPLACE (SUSCRIBER_ID,'^\D*',NULL),
                                             NULL,
                                             SUSCRIBER_ID,
                                             REGEXP_REPLACE (SUSCRIBER_ID,'^\D*',NULL))
```

I believe you need a final default argument with the `REGEXP_REPLACE()` itself.

As @AlexPoole said , Other way is using `NVL()`

```
UPDATE table_name SET SUSCRIBER_ID = NVL (REGEXP_REPLACE (SUSCRIBER_ID,'^\D*',NULL),
                                          SUSCRIBER_ID);
```

Comment: To avoid repetition I'd make that `NVL(REGEXP_REPLACE (SUSCRIBER_ID,'^\D*',NULL), SUSCRIBER_ID)`, but some people prefer the clarity of decode or case...